# AWS lambda Python Expecting ',' delimiter exception

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Python lambda function in which I want to call another lambda function. 
I have a working hardcoded Payload, which I tried to reproduce to suit my use case a bit better. Therefore definition of payload_dict with the same data.

I also attached the prints of the respected usages as an inline comment just in case to hopefully make it a better question.

In short the question is:
How can I make `json.dumps(payload_dict).encode()` work with the same behaviour then the hardcoded version of it inside lambda_client.invoke?
Running on Python 3.6

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import boto3
import sys
import json
import ast

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    startTime = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=0)
    endTime = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

    payload_dict = {}
    payload_dict['instanceID'] = "i-id"
    payload_dict['StartTime'] = startTime.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
    payload_dict['EndTime'] = endTime.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')

    print("PAYLOAD: ",json.dumps(payload_dict).encode()) # b'{"instanceID": "i-id", "StartTime": "2018-08-03 19:11:32", "EndTime": "2018-08-02 19:11:32"}'

    #actually working payload
     payload=b"""{
       "instanceID": "i-id",
       "StartTime": "2018-08-01 00:00:00",
       "EndTime": "2018-08-02 00:00:00"
      }"""
#b'{"instanceID": "i-id","StartTime": "2018-08-01 00:00:00", "EndTime": "2018-08-02 00:00:00"}'
```

Call the other lambda:

```
invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="daily_average_cpu_utilisation_lambda",
                                           InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                                           LogType='Tail',
                                           Payload = payload
                                           )
```

Error that happens when getting information from `lambda_client.invoke` with `json.dumps(payload_dict).encode()` as a payload while calling 
`percentage_usage = invoke_response['Payload'].read().decode('utf8').replace("'", '"'`)
:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 289 (char 288)",
  "errorType": "JSONDecodeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      46,
      "lambda_handler",
      "percentage_dict = json.loads(percentage_usage)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
      354,
      "loads",
      "return _default_decoder.decode(s)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
      339,
      "decode",
      "obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
      355,
      "raw_decode",
      "obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Hopefully it is a good question, and would really appreciate any help, I just fail to see or debug at least for now how could seemingly the same load be interpreted so differently, it could as well be just something obvious that I missed

Comment: To help us reproduce, could you please edit your question and include _all relevant code_? For example, the `import` statements? Also, are you using Python 2.7 or 3.6? When I try to reproduce, I get: `TypeError: isoformat() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated it now and will also double check just in case i didn't miss more info